# How hard is this graph problem?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a problem to solve for a social-networks application, and it sounds hard: I'm not sure if its NP-complete or not. It smells like it might be NP-complete, but I don't have a good sense for these things. In any case, an algorithm would be much better news for me.

Anyhow, the input is some graph, and what I want to do is partition the nodes into two sets so that neither set contains a triangle. If it helps, I know this particular graph is 3-colorable, though I don't actually know a coloring.

Heuristically, a "greedy" algorithm seems to converge quickly: I just look for triangles in either side of the partition, and break them when I find them.

Comment: This sounds interesting; may I ask what application you have for this?

Comment: The http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem may be related.

Comment: Can you give us some constranints? How many nodes and edges can you have?

Comment: I need to solve this for pretty big, but not gigantic graphs (I don't work for facebook =). Something like ~10,000 nodes, and even more edges.

Comment: @Dorian: A dense graph or sparse (M = O(N))?

Comment: Is your graph "locally connected". If it is, apparently you can 3-color it in polynomial time according to this paper (http://www.springerlink.com/content/h2w06m2decm37v5d/)

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. "Locally Connected" as defined in the abstract to that paper seems like a pretty stringent condition, since it has to hold for every vertex in the graph...

Answer (score 3):

The decision version of problem is NP-Complete for general graphs: http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~optas/papers/G-free-complex.pdf and is applicable not just for triangles.

Of course, that still does not help resolve the question for the search version of 3-colourable graphs and triangle freeness (the decision version is trivially in P).

Comment: Hm, interesting. Thanks for the pointer to monochromatic triangle, I had never heard of that problem. Also, interesting about max degree <= 3. Its not always true on the graphs I'm interested in, but that might be good intuition for why the heuristic seems to work...

Comment: Interesting. That seems like a strong condition though, and definitely not true in general. (Consider a tri-partite graph, with 3 large independent sets, but with edges (u,v) between every pair of vertices u and v that are in different parts).

I don't know about my graphs.. Certainly my graphs have minimum degree <= 3, but that sounds like a lot to ask for for -every- subgraph...

Comment: @Dorian: Yeah, good counter-example. I will edit the post to refect that. It could still work though, as at each step you just need to see if that vertex can be added to any of the partitions. I take it your graph keeps changing?

Comment: There is a simple proof that a triangle-free partition always exists for a 3-colorable graph: put all the red vertices in one part, and the green and blue vertices in the other. The problem with applying it here is that we're given only a "promise" of 3-colorability, not an actual coloring.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Right. So I guess any heuristic for 3-coloring of sparse graphs can be applied here to probably get reasonable results.

Comment: Of course, that does not help prove NP-hardness or give a polynomial time algorithm. I am inclined to believe that this problem has a polynomial time algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea that might work. I doubt this is the ideal algorithm, so other people, please build off of this.

Go through your graph and find all the triangles first. I know it seems ridiculous, but it wouldn't be too bad complexity-class wise, I think. You can find any triangles a given node is part of just by following all its edges three hops and seeing if you get to where you started. (I suspect there's a way to get all of the triangles in a graph that's faster than just finding the triangles for each node.)

Once you have the triangles, you should be able to split them any way you please. By definition, once you split them up, there are no more triangles left, so I don't think you have to worry about connections between the triangles or adjacent triangles or anything horrible like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for any set with 5 tightly interconnected nodes, and I can prove it with a simple thought experiment.  5 tightly interconnected nodes is very common in social networks; a cursory glance at my facebook profile found with among my family members and one among a group of coworkers.

By 'tightly interconnected graph', I mean a set of nodes where the nodes have a connection to every other node.  5 nodes like this would look like a star within a pentagon.

Lets start with a set of 5 cousins named Anthony, Beatrice, Christopher, Daniel, and Elisabeth.  As cousins, they are all connected to each other.

1) Lets put Anthony in Collection #1.
2) Lets put Beatrice in Collection #1.
3) Along comes Christopher through our algorithm... we can't put him in collection #1, since that would form a triangle.  We put him in Collection #2.
4) Along comes Daniel.  We can't put him in collection #1, because that would form a triangle, so we put him in Collection #2.
5) Along comes Elisabeth.  We can't put her in Collection #1, because that would form a triangle with Anthony and Beatrice.  We can't put her in Collection #2, because that would for a triangle with Christopher and Daniel.

Even if we varied the algorithm to put Beatruce in Collection #2, the thought experiment concludes with a similar problem.  Reordering the people causes the same problem.  No matter how you pace them, the 5th person cannot go anywhere - this is a variation of the 'pidgenhole principle'.

Even if you loosened the requirement to ask "what is the smallest number of graphs I can partition a graph into so that there are no triangles, I think this would turn into a variation of the Travelling Salesman problem, with no definitive solution.

Comment: OP's graph is 3-colorable. A complete 5-graph is not 3-colorable.

Comment: Your example graph isn't 3-colorable. Its always possible to do this with a 3-colorable graph: put the red vertices on the left, and the blue and green vertices on the right. The problem is its NP hard to find a 3-coloring, so this isn't an algorithm.

Comment: The original question didn't state this is 3-colorable - it stated this is a 'social-networks application', which if users a free to socialize, will result in sub-graphs like the one I posited.

Comment: Not a big deal, but as you can see, the original question has not been edited.

Answer (score -1):

### MY ANSWER IS WRONG

I'll keep it up for discussion. Please don't down vote, the idea might still be helpful.

---

I'm going to argue that it's NP-hard based on the claim that coloring a 3-colorable graph with 4 colors is NP-hard ([*On the hardness of 4-coloring a 3-collorable graph*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=856749)).

> We give a new proof showing that it is NP-hard to color a 3-colorable graph using just four colors. This result is already known, but our proof is novel as [...]

Suppose we can partition a 3-colorable graph into 2 sets A, B, such that neither has a triangle, in polynomial time. Then we can solve the 4-coloring as follows:

- color set A with C1,C2 and set B with C3,C4.
- each set is 2-colorable since it has no triangle **<- THIS IS WHERE I GOT IT WRONG**
- 2-coloring a 2-colorable graph is polynomial
- we have then 4-colored a 3-colorable graph in polynomial time

Through this reduction, I claim that what you are doing must be NP-hard.

Comment: Hm, I don't follow your argument. Why is "each set 2-colorable since it has no triangle"?

Comment: I think this is false, actually.

Comment: -1: For confusing odd cycles with triangles, but interesting idea though.

Answer (score -1):

This problem has an O(n^5) algorithm I think, where n is the number of vertices.

Comment: "Listen pal, you can just waltz in here, use my toaster and spout universal truths without qualification!"